# PHP - Wrong SELECT - Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advertisements WHERE exposure!='0' AND `status`='2' AND clicks_left_micro>0 OR clicks_left_mini>0 OR clicks_left_standard>0 OR clicks_left_extended>0");
```

The above code, should ONLY get the 2 first rows, in my database. (Please check the pic below):
http://i51.tinypic.com/dejiw.png

Why does it select all 3 rows, when I specifically say **status="2"**?

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you have:

```
SELECT * FROM advertisements 
WHERE exposure!='0' 
AND `status`='2' 
AND clicks_left_micro>0 
OR clicks_left_mini>0 
OR clicks_left_standard>0 
OR clicks_left_extended>0
```

But I think that this is what you actually wanted:

```
SELECT * FROM advertisements 
WHERE exposure!='0' 
AND `status`='2' 
AND (clicks_left_micro>0 
OR clicks_left_mini>0 
OR clicks_left_standard>0 
OR clicks_left_extended>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use parenthesis to respect boolean operators priority.

Comment: How can I include those in the query? Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsling the OR part in parentheses

```
AND clicks_left_micro>0 OR clicks_left_mini>0 OR 
clicks_left_standard>0 OR clicks_left_extended>0
```

changed to

```
AND (clicks_left_micro>0 OR clicks_left_mini>0 OR 
clicks_left_standard>0 OR clicks_left_extended>0)
```

should solve it.